# How common are lightsaber training accidents?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

A lightsaber is a pretty unforgiving weapon. Everyone cuts themselves at least once learning how to wield a sword. How common are lightsaber training accidents?

Comment: That's a pretty strong assertion you've got there, care to back it up? My understanding is that most people who take up the sword, do so with practice swords, so they don't cut themselves. Seems pretty irresponsible to allow someone without sufficient training to use live steel. 
Lightsabres, presumably, would similarly have a practice version that wouldn't let 10 year olds chop each other to bits.

Comment: Possible dupe of [How do Jedi (and Sith) practice light saber duelling safely?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36544/how-do-jedi-and-sith-practice-light-saber-duelling-safely/36552#36552).

Comment: Lightsabers are also usually depicted as shutting down if they're knocked out of the wielder's hand, which presumably reduces accidents. If you ever lose your grip, the dangerous bit vanishes.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how common accidents were (I would assume not extremely unheard of because accidents do happen), but I do know that the Jedi of the Old Republic used Training Lightsabers to avoid injuries from such accidents.

[Training Lighsabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber) were used exactly for that purpose. They were lightsabers in all other aspects, except that their low-power made them safe to train with because they could cause less damage. While the Jedi did not build actual lightsabers until they were already competent in their use, actual lightsabers could vary their power output, allowing them to be safer to use for training.